# Why is continuity needed to substitute value of derivative inside Riemann-Stieltjes Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

Given $f$ increasing on $[a,b]$, $g(x)\in R(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$, $\alpha \in C([a,b])$ and $\alpha \in BV([a,b])$ 
$$
\beta(x)=\int_a^xg(z)d\alpha(z) \text{ on [a,b]}
$$

**Why is the additional assumption $f$ continuous and what theorem if any is needed to show the we can *substitute $d\beta$* in the following?**
$$
\int_a^bfd\beta= \int_a^bfgd\alpha
$$

I thought that by the definition of $\beta$ it is differentiable and continuous on $[a,b]$ and I just did a direct substitution $d\beta=g(x)d\alpha(x)$.  With an unused assumption I am concerned I overlooked something.

Comment: It says f is increasing!

Comment: thanks, but why do we care about that and $f$ continuous when working with $d\beta$?

Comment: I've already shown that $f \in BV([a,b])$ and $\beta$ continuous so $f \in R(\beta)$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, for any increasing $\beta$ on $[a,b]$,
$$ \beta(b) - \beta(a) \geq \int_a^b \beta'(t) dt
$$
$\beta'$ exists a.e. since $\beta$ is increasing, so $\beta'$ is Riemann integrable. The above turns into equality when $\beta$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Why do we care about $f$ when we are working with $d\beta$?  This does not address $f$ is continuous.  We know by definition of $\beta$ that it is differentiable and continuous right?

Comment: @stackabstraction By $f$ I meant $\beta$